# 3CX Login via PHP

Tags: php, authentication, request, 3cx

I am trying to log into the [3cx](https://www.3cx.com/) AdminPanel via PHP.

The post url where i have to pass the credentials is

**noonecares.com:5001/api/login** If I login via browser the request has the following headers:

- Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
- Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
- Content-Length: #CONTENT_LENGTH#
- Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
- Origin:https://noonecares.com:5001
- Referer:https://noonecares.com/
- X-3CX-Version:15.5.1694.0

**Content***(request payload)*: {Username: "xxxxx", Password: "xxxxxx"}

In Php I use this headers too

```
    $opts = [
        "http" => [
            "method" => "POST",
            "header" =>
                "Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*\n\r" .
                "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br\n\r" .
                "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8\n\r" .
                "Origin:https://noonecares.com:5001\n\r" .
                "Referer:https://noonecares.com:5001\n\r" .
                "Content-Length:" . strlen($data) . "\n\r",

            "content" => json_encode(["Username" => "xxxxx","Password" => "xxxxxx"]),
        ]
    ];
```

And I try to send the request with the following code:

```
    $result = file_get_contents("noonecares.com:5001/api/login", false, stream_context_create($opts));
```

But I always get "BAD REQUEST" as response and after a couble of tries I get a timeout for around

regards Max

Comment: I am not sure if this fixes your problem, but usually it should be `\r\n` and not `\n\r`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
$opts = [
    "https" => [
```

instead of

```
$opts = [
    "http" => [
```

You can also try this

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://noonecares.com:5001/api/login", false, stream_context_create($opts));
```